# Google script insert value in a column if another column has a specific value

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script

as basic as this may sound I am having difficulty writing this. I have two columns with checkboxes in a sheet(main) and I want to be able to checkbox(true) column 'O' if column 'm' has a checkmark after I am done with the sheet(macro button).
Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0):

#### If M is true set O to true

```
function lfunko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const [hA,...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    if(r[12] == "TRUE") {
      sh.getRange(i + 2, 15).setValue("TRUE");
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Hey Cooper, thanks for the reply. The script is not performing as needed, actually isn't "doing" anything.. What is the "hA" in the const string for? Shouldn't "r[12]" be 13?
Thanks again.

Comment: Try it any way you like.